# how to setup mongodb replica on cloud server?

Tags: transaction, transactional-replication, mongodb-3.4, amazon-ec2

I want to setup mongodb repicaset on my cloud server(AWS ec2) but I have only one IP address. 
Currently I have make /etc/hosts two entries `127.0.0.1 dbnode1` and `xx.xx.xx.xx dbnode2` but when I try to reconfig rs config its give error.

Error:- Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: node1:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: node2:27019 failed with Error connecting to node2:27019 (127.0.0.2:27019) :: caused by :: Connection refused

Can anyone suggest how to I can setup replica or without setup replica how to use transaction query.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set up replica set of two (or more) nodes at one physical server... You must use IP-addresses and not host names. So 127.0.0.1:27017, 127.0.0.1:27019